# Convert .dmp file to .hprof file

Tags: java, heap-dump, jmap

I have tried running the command

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=jvm.hprof core.20170103.212745.20453.0007.dmp
```

But i get an error

```
Error attaching to remote server: java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: core.20170103.212745.20453.0007.dmp; nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: core.20170103.212745.20453.0007.dmp
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: java.rmi.UnknownHostException:
```

What is the error? I tried putting it on a TomCat server and running it but still throws an error

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the "executable" parameter, so jmap thinks you're trying to connect to a remote host.
try something like:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=jvm.hprof /usr/bin/java core.20170103.212745.20453.0007.dmp
```

Comment: @t-josef How do i add that in windows?

Comment: Same idea... with quotes over spaces in file names:
`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\jmap.exe" -dump:format=b,file=jvm.hprof "C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin\java.exe" core.20170103.212745.20453.0007.dmp`